# Where does Elementor plugin keeps template pages?

Tags: wordpress, elementor

I need to find a specific line of code on my website foodhide.pl (password is "11111" if someone would like to see it) page that is build with elementor plugin. Hovewer I can't find where does Elementor keeps these templates.

I've tried searching for a post id which is "2909" but nothing seems to pop up.

Appreciate any help on this topic!

Answer (score 0):

Got an answer directly from Elementor support.

> Elementor uses JSON format for the templates, The only option to paste an Elementor template to a page not built from Elementor is to
>   use shortcodes. You can copy the shortcode of the template and paste
>   it to the page made with Wordpress.
>
> If you do wish to get the code of the template made with Elementor,
>   unfortunately, there is no option to achieve it directly.